# Test script if host is back online

Tags: linux, ping, notifications

E.g. system: Ubuntu/Debian.

As many of you do this probably via ping and a terminal, I always forget this terminal when switching to other task. So a notification pop-up would be useful. So can I do better as this?

```
while; do
  if ping -c 1 your.host.com; expr $? = 0; then
     notify-send "your.host.com back online"; sleep 30s;
  else
     sleep 30s;
  fi;
done
```

You will need *zsh* and *libnotify* to let the snippet work. As script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
while; do if ping -c 1 $1; expr $? = 0; then notify-send "$1 back online"; sleep 30s; else sleep 30s; fi; done
```

Comment: Quick refactoring suggestion: make it a function which accepts the hostname/IP address as argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea looks right to me.  By using `while :; do ...` you can make it portable to normal Bourne shells.  The `expr` calls seems unnecessary.  Also, you probably want to break out of the loop when the host is found.

```
while :; do
    if ping -c 1 $1; then
        notify-send "$1 back online"
        break
    fi
    sleep 30s
done
```